# Joomla how to reset pagination to start

Tags: joomla, pagination, reset

In my list view, I would like to start always at the begin and not at the last visited pagination position.

How can I reset the list.start for pagination?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's a way to actually configure what you're asking, but adding `&limitstart=0` to the url will tell Joomla to start at the beginning.  Perhaps the folks at [joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) could offer more insight if this isn't sufficient.

Comment: I would like to do it via setState Methode